# Maven POM: how to insist property is not overridden

Tags: inheritance, maven, properties, pom.xml

I have a parent POM that uses a gmaven script to do some stuff:

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>

      <configuration combine.children="override">
        <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        <scriptPath>${basedir}/build/groovy</scriptPath>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>groovy-properties-script</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <source>computeProperties.groovy</source>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
          <!-- ... -->
```

All of the children are supposed to run this script as well, but they try to resolve the scriptpath based on their OWN basedir. Usually this is exactly what you want with properties, but here it doesn't work, and I can't figure out any way around it.

Comment: Why don't you hard code the path? Such things don't change often in build process.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this seems to be to use the `set-system-properties` goal of the `properties-maven-plugin`, thusly:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>com.binu.core.parent.basedir</name>
              <value>${basedir}</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Because it is not inherited, this plugin will only run in the parent pom. This seems rather hacky though, is there a native maven way to achieve this?

Comment: UPDATE:: this doesn't work. Even though set-system-properties has added the property, maven doesnt see it. It seems that maven (3.0.2) must read system properties at startup and ignore them henceforth.

If I instead use 

                <source>evaluate(new File(System.getProperty("com.binu.core.parent.basedir") + "/build/groovy/computeProperties.groovy"))</source>

as the source for the gmaven plugin, it works. But this is even MORE hacky.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do these kind of things is to put your groovy scripts in its own jar file and have `maven-dependency-plugin` unpack it for you. Then your script can point to the unpacked script.

Like this example:

`directory layout`

```
+- pom.xml
  +- script
  | +- pom.xml
  | +- src
  |   +- main
  |     +- resources
  |       +-computeProperties.groovy
  +- code
    +- pom.xml
    +- src
      +- main
        +- java
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q11321971</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>script</module>
        <module>code</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Inter-Module dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>Q11321971-script</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>Q11321971-script</artifactId>
                                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/build/groovy</outputDirectory>
                                        <includes>**/*.groovy</includes>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

`script/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q11321971</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q11321971-script</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

</project>
```

`code/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q11321971</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q11321971-code</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you run this top pom you will find that in the `target` directory of the `code` module there is now `build/groovy/computeProperties.groovy` that you can refer to in your plugin.

This will work from all modules even for the parent pom by adding this to the `<build/>` tag of the parent:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The parent will now have a `target` directory with `build/groovy/computeProperties.groovy` in it.

In your plugin you can change the `<scriptPath/>` to this:

```
<scriptPath>${project.build.directory}/build/groovy</scriptPath>
```

And since the `maven-dependency-plugin` is now running in the `validate` phase then the `gmaven-plugin` must run in a later phase. That is something that you can elaborate like you want.

The very good thing about doing it this way is that if someone only wants to check out a child module then they can run it and the script jar will be downloaded from the repo and being used.

No relative paths needed...